# Read Properties file in WSO2 mediator

Tags: wso2, properties-file

for example, if my **link.properties** file contains 
phone= http://localhost:8080/Validation/phone
placed in **cofig folder**, how the value phone be accessed in a mediator(proxy mediator).

Answer (score 1):

You can use class mediator to read the properties file and load values from there.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your properties file should be located in the *<project name>/src/main/resources* directory, you can use this method for reading property files:

```
import import java.util.Properties;
import java.net.URL;

Properties readPropertiesFile() {
    
    // Looks for "application.properties" in "<project name>/src/main/resources"
    URL fileUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("application.properties");

    Properties applicationProperties = new Properties();
    try {
        // Load properties from file
        applicationProperties.load(fileUrl.openStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // File not found, invalid permissions, usual file handling stuff...
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return applicationProperties;
}
```

You can read the property like this:

```
Properties applicationProperties = readPropertiesFile();
if (applicationProperties == null) {
    // null handling
}

String yourProperty = (String) applicationProperties.get("your.property.name");
```